# How can I add an already created node to a linked list?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to add an already created node to a linked list by passing a pointer to pointer as argument. I can't figure out how to make it work.

```
void List::add(Node* n, int pos){
    if(pos > size)
        pos = size;
    
    if(pos == 0){
        if (head == NULL){
            head = n;
        }
        else{
            Node* temp = head;
            n->setNext(temp);
            head = n;
        }
    }
    else{
        Node* temp = head;
        int currPos = 0;
        while(temp->getNext() != NULL && currPos != pos){
            temp = temp->getNext();
            currPos++;
            }
        if(currPos == pos){
            Node* next = temp->getNext();
            n->setNext(next);
            }
            
    temp->setNext(n);
            
    }
    size++; 
}
```

I implemented a method that creates a new node for each call and it works fine, but I need to work with already created nodes.

Below you have the header files for List and Node.

```
#pragma once
#include "Node.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class List{
        Node* head;
        int size;
    
    public:
        List();
        List(const Team&, Node* = NULL);
    //  List(const List&);
    //  List& operator=(const List&);
        ~List();
        void add(const Team&, int = 0);
        void add(Node*, int = 0);
        void remove(const Team&);
        void removeLowest(int unqualNum);
        void print() const;
        void printNames(ostream& o = cout) const;
        int getSize() const;
        Node* getHead() const;
};



#pragma once
#include "Team.hpp"

class Node{
        Team value;
        Node* next;
    
    public:
        Node(const Team& = Team(), Node* = NULL);
    //  Node(const Node&);
    //  operator=(const Node&);
    //  ~Node();
        Team getValue() const;
        void setValue(const Team&);
        Node* getNext() const;
        void setNext(Node*);
};
```

I have another class Stack where I want to use the method.

```
    #pragma once
#include "Node.hpp"
#include "List.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class Stack{
    Node* head;
    int size;
    
    public:
        Stack();
        Stack(const Team&, Node* = NULL);
    //  Stack(const Stack&);
    //  Stack& operator=(const Stack&);
        ~Stack();
        
        void push(const Team&);
        void pop();
        void print(ostream& = cout) const;
        
        int getSize() const;
        Node* getHead() const;
        
        void toList(List* );
};
```

In method toList, I try to move all the nodes of the stack to a list passed as argument.

```
void Stack::toList(List* l){
    Node *temp = head;
    while(temp){
        l->add(temp->getValue(), l->getSize()); // This works similar add method that build node inside
        l->add(temp, l->getSize()); // This doesn't, the method with Node as parameter
        temp = temp->getNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you observe?

Comment: I get a seg fault.

Comment: And where exactly do you get the segfault, may I ask?

Comment: @StefanNastase Why are you creating nodes outside of the list to begin with? That is a bad code smell. Only the `List` class should be creating any nodes for itself.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan i think when I'm setting the next for *n

Comment: @RemyLebeau i have a Stack of same type of nodes and I want to move the nodes to my List

Comment: Well that is a pretty good hint that `*n` is not pointing to an allocated memory. Are you sure your node is properly allocated?

Comment: @StefanNastase Why do you have a stack of `Node`s, and not a stack of `Team`s?  In any case, please provide a [mcve] showing how you are using `add()` with existing `Node`s. Your implementation of `add()` is not very good and can (and should) be simplified, but none of that will matter if the input from the stack is bad to begin with.

Comment: Why `Node**` not just `Node*` ?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan well, if I create a new node right before the add, it does work, but when I try to add the existing stack's head to the list it doesn't

Comment: @RemyLebeau I had to implement the stack myself, that's why I used nodes.

Comment: @bloody It doesn't work with Node* either. I used Node** because I call a setter on the node

Comment: Would suggest insertion similar to [C linked list w/head/tail](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) or for a full [C++ template implementation](https://pastebin.com/Sq1MPU15) For explanation of iterating both with the address of nodes and pointer to nodes, see: [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/)

Comment: You do several things with `*n` but you always dereference this. Simpler would be taking `Node* n` and use just `n` everywhere.

Comment: @bloody ok, I changed that

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added a little bit more code, I hope It's more clearly now

Comment: @StefanNastase You are attempting to move each existing `Node` from the `Stack` to the `List`. But you are not releasing the `Stack`'s ownership of the `Node`s, which will cause problems later when the `Stack` goes to free the `Node`s while the `List` is still using them. And, you are iterating the `Stack`'s `Node`s individually but you are not unlinking them from each other before moving them into the `List`. So, you are going to end up corrupting not only the `Stack` and the `List`, but also your iteration as well. This is just bad coding all around.

Comment: @StefanNastase I think you should get rid of `add(Node*)` altogether until you have a better handle on pointers and memory management.  `toList()` should just use `add(Team)` to make a *copy* of the `Node` data without altering the `Stack`'s content at all.